# How should I sand before the final coat of polyurethane?

Tags: hardwood-floor, sanding, polyurethane, hardwood-refinishing

I have applied 3 coats of poly so far. I'd like to smooth out the surface before the final coat. What type of sander should I use: Square Buff Floor Sander [image: Square Buff Floor Sander],

Random Orbit Floor Sander [image: Random Orbit Floor Sander],

or just a hand held orbital [image: hand held orbital]?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depends on the quality of the existing finish... if it's as flat as you want it to be, then I'd kiss it with 150 on a pole sander.

[image]
<sup>Link for illustration purposes only: there are many out there...</sup>

If you need to knock down blobs/ runs/ etc, then start with 120 on the handheld random orbit sander. Work your way up to 150/220.

Vacuum and then wipe with a compatible tack cloth to remove dust and residue.

If you're having a hard time laying down a perfect coat, make the last one a bit thin -- 10-20% added paint thinner -- and it'll flow better. Also, don't skimp on the brush quality.

Comment: +1, pole sander. Once you start varnishing you're done with power tools.